# How to tie up express sessions with socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

How to tie up sessions in express 4 with socket.io so session data can be both retrieved and saved in both directions?

Authentication in socket.io is token-based with `jwt`

The same socket is shared in multiple vhosts

eg:

```
global.socket.of('/secure').on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('client connected to "secure" socket');
});
```

app.js

```
var port = 3000,
    jwtSecret = '26fed98d8c6c7c54f485f1ee7ffe44d2e1feae28';

var app = require('express')(),
    vhost = require('vhost'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

//  Start server with socket.io
global.socket = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port '+port);
}));

//  Socket authentication
global.socket.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: jwtSecret,
    handshake: true
}));

//  Virtual hosts
app.use(vhost('secure.domain.com', require('./vhost/secure')(jwtSecret)));
```

vhost/secure.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function Host(jwtSecret){
    var app = express();

    //  Session
    app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
    app.use(require('express-session')({
        secret: '0a6e0caf5477cee686726ad06284309eb4a580e4',
        key: 'express.sid',
        cookie: {
            maxAge : 1000*60*10
        }
    }));

    //  HTTP 200
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.end('helle world!');
    });

    app.post('/login', function(req, res){
        var profile = {
            id: 1,
            name: 'username'
        };
        var token = jwt.sign(profile, jwtSecret, {expiresInMinutes: 60});
        res.json({token: token});
    });

    global.socket.of('/secure').on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('client connected to "secure" socket');

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('client disconnected from "secure" socket');
        });
    });

    return http.createServer(app);
}

module.exports = Host;
```